# How to stop spaCy tokenizer from tokenizing words enclosed within brackets

Tags: python, string, nlp, spacy, tokenize

I'm trying to make the spaCy tokenizer avoid certain words enclosed by brackets, like `[intervention]`. However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the right code to include a rule or an exception.  Here is an example of some input and the expected output:

**Example input:**

> A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial resection[intervention] to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial polyps[condition]

**Example output:**

```
A
randomized
,
prospective
study
of
[intervention]
endometrial
resection
[intervention]
to
prev

... et cetera
```

I've tried adding a special case like this:

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

case = [{ORTH: "[intervention]"}]
    
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('[intervention]',case)
    
# Test the custom tokenizer
text = combined_abstracts
doc = nlp(text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

But the tokenizer is still splitting the word. Does anybody know a way to either make the tokenizer ignore certain words or all of the words enclosed by brackets? Either option would be useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to be defined to achieve the desired result:

1. Specify that square brackets should be treated as valid [infixes](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers) (i.e. something that spaCy should treat as a non-whitespace separator when tokenizing). This will allow the subsequently defined special cases to work. Any additional infixes should usually be added/concatenated to the existing pipeline's defaults.
2. Specify the [special cases](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#add_special_case) (i.e. what "cases" [spaCy should treat](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases) as a single token). In your case, these are medical term descriptions enclosed by square brackets.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH

txt = (
    "A randomized, prospective study of [intervention]endometrial"
    " resection[intervention] to prevent [condition]recurrent endometrial"
    " polyps[condition]"
)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Specify and then tell the pipeline that square brackets should be valid infixes
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + [r"([\[\]])"]
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer

# Define the words that will be found within the square brackets
tags = [
    "intervention",
    "condition",
]

# Add the special cases to the tokenizer
for tag in tags:
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"[{tag}]", [{ORTH: f"[{tag}]"}])

# Process and print text
doc = nlp(txt)
for tok in doc:
    print(tok.text)
```

Output:

```
A
randomized
,
prospective
study
of
[intervention]
endometrial
resection
[intervention]
to
prevent
[condition]
recurrent
endometrial
polyps
[condition]
```